# Select key:value with jq and output as array

Tags: json, bash, csv, output, jq

When using jq it is easy to select a key:value that you want to output, but by default the array dissapears. How do I keep the output as an array?

## Example

```
# My JSON
my_json='{"count":2,"values":[{"name": "Hans","age": 22},{"name": "John","age": 88}]}'

# Getting names
echo $my_json | jq ".values[].name"
"Hans"
"John"
```

## What I want

```
["Hans", "John"]
```

With an output like that I can e.g. remove the quotes by outputting it to tsv.

```
# Output to tsv
echo '["Hans", "John"]' | jq -r '.[]'
```

Comment: This is a mapping from one array to another: `jq -c '.values | map(.name)' <<< "$my_json"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add *square brackets* (*preferably* along with ***c***(*ompact output*) option in order to return the array on a single line as in the question) such as

```bash
echo $my_json | jq -c '[.values[].name]'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/s0mDVdSv4wq)</kbd>

Comment: I tried the demo and it seems like compact is only a formatting option. Maybe remove it from the answer because it distracts from the real solution, adding the square brackets.

Comment: well, I've edited to express my intention. Thanks @ZachYoung

Answer (score 1):

No need for two commands. You can directly get

```
Hans
John
```

by using

```bash
printf %s "$my_json" | jq -r '.values[].name'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/5UArwDCyI7B) on jqplay